# Android - Error signing my apk wit jarsigner

Tags: android, apk

I made a key file like this:

```
C:\Users\Alex>keytool -genkey -v -keystore alexkey.keystore -alias alexkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

and then I tried to sign my .apk file with it like this:

```
C:\>jarsigner -verbose -keystore alexkey.keystore problemio.apk alexkey
```

and I saved the .apk file by right-clicking the project name in Eclipse --> Android tools --> Export unsigned application package.

and then I put the .apk file in the same dir as the key, and ran the jarsigner command from that same dir.

Any idea why I got this error:

```
jarsigner: unable to create: problemio.apk.sig
```

Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem once, and was because a little error that I didn't noticed appeared, when I was cleaning the code, before signing it!!

Comment: @PedroTeran so its a problem somewhere in the code? Any idea what it might be? And not a problem in my key-generation process? Thanks!!

Comment: @yorkw Java version 1.6 - would that make a difference?

Comment: If you are running Windows 7, make sure you have proper write permission to JDK directory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Credit to @yorkw for the answer, the real solution to this problem is a folder permissions issue. Make sure you are operating in a folder that you can modify. I just fixed that same problem for my self by making sure I was in a folder with the right permissions.

Answer (score 9):

This error is related to permission issues.

1. Check the folder(Full permission is there or not)
2. Run as administrator for command prompt

Comment: Worked on mac when running as 'sudo'

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

### For Windows Users

open your terminal or command prompt with administrative access

### For Ubuntu/linux Users

run `jarsigner` with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Have Access permission to the path where jarsigner is located. It will surely work.! :-)

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question