# Error publishing Android app due to jarsigner and unaligned.apk

Tags: android, meteor

I am following the exact [instructions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store) from Meteor to publish an Android app. I've made progress, but towards the end I am getting an error.

```
>>>> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 unaligned.apk your-app-name

Enter Passphrase for keystore: 

jarsigner: unable to open jar file: unaligned.apk
```

I am not sure how to even debug this problem. I've searched the Internet but haven't found any solutions. Can anyone here provide some advice? Thanks very much.

Comment: Check This---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833024/android-error-signing-my-apk-wit-jarsigner                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396185/jarsigner-is-unable-to-open-jar-file-nooyawk-apk-nooyawk-is-app-name                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089042/jarsigner-unable-to-sign-jar-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-entry-compres             https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5672                    http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that they renamed the file to `release-unsigned.apk`, so I have to do

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 unaligned.apk your-app-name
```